# using blade layouts to Extend Templates

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5, laravel-blade

i am new comer in laravel.i am trying to extend template using blade layouts but it failed.since the navbar and footer are fixed almost all the web pages so i am trying to put navbar and footer in parent page and it will be extendable to the middle content page that means child page.

following code  for master page.

> views/bootstrap/layouts/master.blade.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>@yield('title')</title>
  {!!Html::style('css/bootstrap.min.css')!!}
  
</head>
<body>

@section('navbar')
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
@show

@yield('content')

@section('footer')
<h3>This is Footer section </h3>
@show
{!!Html::script('js/jquery.min.js')!!}
{!!Html::script('js/bootstrap.min.js')!!}
</body>
</html>
```

following code for child page

> views/bootstrap/about.blade.php

```html
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('title', 'Bootstrap-About')

@section('content')

<nav>
  <li>Mamun</li>
  <li>Web Developer</li>
  <li>Bangla Trac Miaki Vas Ltd.</li>
  <li>Banani</li>
</nav>

@stop
```

above code only shows content values nothing else.but if i put them only one page it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to extend wrong master view. if your master.blade is in the views/bootstrap/master.blade.php then

```
    @extends('bootstrap.layouts.master')
    @section('title', 'Bootstrap-About')

    @section('content')

    <nav>
      <li>Mamun</li>
      <li>Web Developer</li>
      <li>Bangla Trac Miaki Vas Ltd.</li>
      <li>Banani</li>
    </nav>

    @stop
```